# A question about drawing a line throught n connected, pairwise intersecting regions.

Tags: puzzle

A friend asked me this: Given n connected regions in space, and any pair of regions has no empty intersection, is it possible to draw a line through all of the regions?

Comment: @angryavian - to the extent that the triangle meets the precondition, we must consider a vertex to belong to both edges, in which case it is very possible to draw a line from a vertex to the opposing side thus touching all 3 edges.

Comment: @antkam Thanks for catching my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Not only is a line through all regions possible, you can in fact choose any orientation you like and find a line of that orientation through all regions.

E.g. how about a line parallel to the $y$-axis?  Such a line is defined by $x=c$ for some constant $c$.  For region $A$, let $x(A)$ denote the set of $x$ values contained in the region, i.e.,

$$x(A) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists y: (x,y) \in A\}$$

So the line $x=c$ intersects $A$ iff $c \in x(A)$.  This being a puzzle, I don't want to give the whole solution away, so...

- Each region is connected.  What does that say about $x(A)$?
- Every pair of regions $A,B$ overlaps.  What does that say about $x(A), x(B)$?

Can you finish from here?

Comment: $x(A)$ and $x(B)$ has no empty intersection for all $A$ and $B$. Also, $x(A)$ and $x(B)$ are intervals of the form $(a_A,b_A),(a_B,b_B)$. So $a_i \leq b_i \forall i$. So max of all $a_i$ could be our $c$?

Comment: Yes $c = \max a_i$ works.  I love this puzzle.  It sounds so complicated and general, and I found myself doodling overlapping blobs with weird shapes, but turns out to be almost a trick question with such a simple answer.  (BTW technically the intervals are closed, i.e. $[a_A, b_A]$.)